# Migration for Administrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a minor issue.  I added administrate gem, ran bundle install, and rails g install:administrate.  When I run rails db:migrate, nothing happens.  Any clues?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be `rails g administrate:install`. It should add  some new routes to your `config/routes.rb`, and create `app/controllers/admin/` and `app/dashboards/` folder with bucnh of files. No needs in additional `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks, Vasillisa.  Someone else informed me that the migration isn't needed.  Again, thanks for your time.